# Equivalence classes of a circle of n bits upon flipping 3 consecutive 0s to 1s or vice versa

Tags: co.combinatorics, invariant-theory

Consider a circle of n-bits and define the equivalence relation as follow:

Two configurations A and B of the n-bits circle are equivalent if they can be transformed into each other by performing a sequence of *"3-bit flip"* operations.

Here the *"3-bit flip"* can **only flip 3 consecutive 1s to 0s or vice-versa, namely 111<->000**.

The question is how to compute the equivalence class of the n-bits string on a circle? **Note that the only operation allowed is the *"3-bit flip"*, any other operations such as overall rotation are not allowed in the equivalence relation.** I guess that there will be a lot of invariants that characterize the equivalent classes, but I can only construct a small number of them (such as the numbers of 0s module 3).

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: The sequence begins (with n=3): 7, 8, 13, 27, 32, 51, 98, 130, 210, 374, 542, 872, 1505, 2268, 3663, 6197, 9552, 15429, 25880, 40298, 65146, 108588, 170266, 275296, 457119, 719864, 1164165, 1927235, 3044980. Code to calculate this: https://github.com/Pazzaz/equivalence-classes . (I reposted this comment as I noticed I had made a mistake)

Comment: Hi Pazzaz, thank you for the answer! I used BFS to classify all binary strings and got the same answer!

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear if you consider $n$-bit circular strings up to rotations, and this would affect the answer. Still, in either case a rough idea is as follows.

Transform $111$ to $000$ until no $111$ remains in the string. Then the string is formed by runs of $0$'s separated by $1$ or $11$. Notice that we can move $000$ from one run to a neighboring run with two $3$-bit flips, and so we can assume that there is at most one run of $0$'s of length $\geq 3$. Hence, there are two major types of equivalence classes:

- There is no run of $0$'s of length $\geq 3$. Such classes are classified by a sequence of run lengths $(u_1,z_1,\dots,u_k,z_k)$ for some $k\geq 1$, where $u_i\in\{1,2\}$ is the $i$-th run length of $1$'s and $z_i\in\{1,2\}$ is the $i$-th run length of $0$'s, with $u_1+z_1+\dots+u_k+z_k=n$.
- There exists a run of $0$'s of length $\geq 3$. Such classes are classified by a sequence of run lengths $(u_1,z_1,\dots,u_k)$ for some $k\geq 0$, where again $u_i,z_i\in\{1,2\}$, and $u_1+z_1+\dots+u_k\leq n-3$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Previously I thought the circular strings that only differ by rotation are in the same class, then I realized that it may not be the case. Thank you for pointing it out! I have edited the post to clarify this.

Comment: Hi Max, while I agree with the classification of your first-type classes ("frozen class"), I think some classes in your second-type classes may be equivalent to each other. For example, for n=8 the string 00000101 and 00001001 are in fact in the same class, because they can be transformed into each other by moving around 000: 00000101->00101000->00001001. I think this is because when we try to eliminate all 111 in a string, there may be multiple ways to do this and may result in multiple "classes" that are in fact equivalent.

Comment: As I said, it's a rough idea. To make the second case more accurate one needs to consider two subcases: (i) all runs of $0$'s (including the longest) have length $\equiv 1\pmod{3}$; and (ii) the longest run has length $\equiv 2\pmod{3}$.